# Como actualizar un DataGrid en tiempo real

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente método que recorre un DataGrid
como ven cada vez que hay una operación exitosa recargar un método `Invoke((MethodInvoker)ListarPagos);` y cada vez que sale del método recarga otro `Invoke((MethodInvoker)ListarLog);`

Estos métodos refrescan unos DataGird, Lo que pasa es que hay un hilo que tiene un bucle infinito
entonces la aplicación se bloquea por estar refrescando estos dos métodos

¿Mi pregunta es como puede refrescar un DataGrid en tiempo real sin tener que estar llamando el método que tiene el DataSource?, he trabajado con SignalR pero no si si esto este para Windows Forms, Si no puedo usar SignalR como podría utilizar algo similar en Forms para que se refresque en tiempo real, y en caso que esto no lo pueda hacer como podría llamar estos métodos sin que se congele la app con el código que tengo.

**"Ensaye la aplicación sin ejecutar los métodos y funciona correctamente, por eso llegue a la conclusión que estos métodos bloquean la app"**

```
private async  void Hilo() 
        {
            try
            {
               ProxyBL proxy = new ProxyBL();
                foreach (DataGridViewRow Datos in GridPagos.Rows)
                {
                    PagosRecibidos pagos = new PagosRecibidos
                    {
                        CardCode = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[0].Value).Trim(),
                        DocType = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[1].Value),
                        Series = Convert.ToInt32(Datos.Cells[2].Value),
                        DocDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datos.Cells[3].Value),
                        DocEntry = Convert.ToInt32(Datos.Cells[5].Value),
                        TrsfrAcct = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[6].Value),
                        TrsfrDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Datos.Cells[7].Value),
                        TrsfrSum = Convert.ToDecimal(Datos.Cells[8].Value),
                        Integration = Convert.ToBoolean(Datos.Cells[9].Value),
                        Comments = Convert.ToString(Datos.Cells[10].Value),
                        SumApplied = Convert.ToDecimal(Datos.Cells[11].Value)
                    };
                    Inte = pagos.Integration;
                    if (Inte == false)
                    {
                        var Respuesta = await proxy.EnviarPago(pagos);
                        if (Respuesta.Contains("true|Operación Exitosa"))
                        {
                          Invoke((MethodInvoker)ListarPagos);
                        }
                    }
                   Invoke((MethodInvoker)ListarLog);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Ciclo que llama el Metodo Hilo

```
   private  async void controladorHilos()
            {
                while (Ciclo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Aquí "esperamos" a que se complete el hilo.
                        await Task.Run(() => Hilo());
                        // Este hilo en específico se detendrá a esperar la llamada.
                        // Si todo sale bien, lo ejecutará de nuevo y esperará una y otra vez.                
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // Si ocurre un error en el hilo lo capturamos aquí.
                        Console.Write("Excepción: " + e.Message);
                    }
                }
                Invoke((MethodInvoker)Controles);
            }
```

Comment: Pregunta duplicada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/486279/mejorar-rendimiento-de-hilo

Comment: @KevinRestrepo esa pregunta está eliminada.

Comment: @Excorpion Si, pero era basicamente lo mismo, creo que por eso la elimino

Comment: Puede que haya renovado, a lo que no comete un error de duplicación, siempre debes esperar a ver si borran la anterior o no .

Comment: Por que tienes que refrescar el datagrid, que es lo que sucede q tienes q refrescarlo?

Comment: Por que a medida que el va enviando los que están en false los pone en true, y los true yo no los muestro en el DataGrid, entonces solo tienen que ir quedando los false

Comment: @Hackerman, no entendí nada de lo que dijiste, q es lo q quieres hacer de q va todo esto, cual es el objetivo final?

Comment: Te sugerimos realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask] para que puedas obtener buenas respuestas, debes evitar duplicar las preguntas en el sitio y evitar usar otra cuenta para esta práctica. Añade información necesaria a tus preguntas para que obtengas la ayuda de parte de la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas. Vamos a revisar el reporte relacionado a votación en serie. saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys, Pero como quieres que eso suceda si cada vez que publico algo lo ponen en negativo, y nadie presta atención por que desde el primer minuto publicada ya tiene un -1.